# How to make a plane mirror in SceneKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

For SCNFloor, if the reflective is set to 1 and reflectionFallOffEnd is big enough, it will be like a mirror.

My question is how to apply this to other geometries (say plane or box)? As I want to have a mirror in my game.

Answer (score 5):

I have done quite a bit of research on how to make reflections using Scenekit.

Here are the different leads I found (sadly, they will all need a serious amount of code and research):

### Screen-Space reflections

**Pros :**

- Cheap
- Easy to make

**Cons**

- Doesn't always look great
- I'm not sure how to output a normal pass with SCNTechnique

### Parallax-mapped cubemaps

**Pros :**

- Cheap
- Looks amazing

**Cons**

- No real time objects unless using an image proxy
- No good code sample online, will need research
- Not quite sure how to use it with SCNProgram

### Two cameras + Stencil

**Pros :**

- Realistic
- Real time
- Almost built in

**Cons**

- No documentation of the `pointOfView` of SCNTechnique
- No documentation on Stencils
- Needs to render the scene twice

### OpenGL mirror

**Pros :**

- Actually duplicates the geometry, so very accurate
- This is the technique used by SCNFloor (I think)

**Cons**

- Geometry can clip with the mirror plane (happens with SCNFloor)
- Unusable on anything other than a plane
- Needs OpenGL Code

### 4 Cameras linked to a Cubemap

**Pros :**

- Easy to set up
- Real time
- Works on any object
- Very popular technique in modern Video Games

**Cons**

- I have no idea if this would work
- Will need to render the scene 5 times for a single mirror
- Not very accurate depending on object

My conclusion is that we need more help on using SCNTechnique. We could build amazing things with it but the lack of documentation and examples is a big problem.

If you could specify what kind of mirror you have in mind, I'll be happy to help you choose the best way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to share what I have done. I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brandosha/133ff52829adde4b97f74bacff5ccc7d) on GitHub that contains the code and explains how it works.

It basically attaches six cameras to a node and automatically creates a cubemap that is then used as the reflective property of the object. The main downside is that it won't work with physically based materials, but in order to simulate roughness, it blurs the cubemap to whatever you set the roughness property to. It works well in real time and you can set how quickly the cubemaps update so that you are not affecting the framerate of your game too much. It can also handle many different reflective objects and automatically stops updating nodes that you can't see.

Comment: Thanks @moustach for the idea to link cameras to a cubemap

Comment: why doesn't this work for physically based materials?

Comment: Oh, I see. It's using `node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.reflective.contents`.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported on other geometry types. Please [file a request to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).